# Automated offset support and/or compression support using phRETS

Tags: php, rets

Is there any automated mechanism to check offset support and/or compression support using [phRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/blob/master/phrets.php)?

Am using the following line of code, once the server supports 'Offset' or 'Compression'.

```
$rets->SetParam("offset_support", true);
$rets->SetParam("compression_enabled", true);
```

So I need an automated solution for checking the support, to set these params.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for Automated offset support from this link,
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phrets/VJC6FNyemhA

it is also mentioning,

> The new upcoming version of RETS (RETS 1.8) has a way for servers to
>   tell you if they support Offset for each class

Edit: [RETS 1.8 documentation](http://www.reso.org/assets/RETS/Specifications/rets_1_8.pdf)